# How to create iOS emulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, emulation

With Xcode, we get a simulator (not an emulator), which is good for various level of testing, but in the end you need device for actual testing. I am interested in creating emulator for various iPhone, iPad, and then different iOS versions.
My question is, can we create an emulator for iOS, if so what could be the approach. I am new to the emulator field, i am an iOS developer, so very much familiar with objective c and iOS sdk. I need to know what skill sets are required for this, and how to proceed. Any ebook, website, most welcome. I am not looking for a perfect answer, a good guideline will work.

Comment: a small doubt:I didn't get what is the purpose for creating an emulator for iPad.Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: A purpose is to get more close behaviour, as simulator has various restrictions, very limited app support, you can not install new apps from app store, if the emulator is there, and then no need to buy the device for app testing, and it can help as there are various iOS devices now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this, but I think if you need to do this you need to compile the source code for `armv7` or `armv7s` processors.

Please check these links, I found during my searching [**iOS Emulator**](http://modmyi.com/content/5195-ios-emulator-underway-iemu-project.html), [**iOS Emulators**](http://devworks.thinkdigit.com/Mobiles-PDAs/iOS-emulators-are-here_9803.html)

Comment: @cocoaNoob: All the best :)